# Why does Ngrok give me this error about port 3000?

Tags: ngrok

I am trying to use NGROK so that I can use BeEF xss, whenever I start it and check the links, I get the error

"was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:3000.

Make sure that a web service is running on localhost:3000 and that it is a valid address.

The error encountered was: dial tcp [::1]:3000: connect: connection refused"

Comment: Are you running anything on port 3000?

Comment: having the same issue if anyone has fixed it yet